# Subclassed Textbox readonly font not recognized on form

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, class

Building my baseclasses for user interface controls is getting there.  I have command buttons derived with custom font assignment and put on a form, all is fine...  However, identical code for the read-only property Font of a textbox is NOT recognized properly on the same form. It is ONLY taking the setting of the FORM and disregarding its own Font declaration.

```
public class MyTextbox : TextBox
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public override Font Font
    { get { return new 
             Font( "Courier New", 12f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point ); 
          } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a help from "nobugz" (Thanks), I found this same failure when doing a ComboBox too.  My result was the following...

My getter

```
get { return new Font( ... ); }
```

However, in nobugz response, something wasn't working quite right with the compiler, so in the constructor of the class

```
clas MyTextbox...
{
   public MyTextbox()
   {
      // it defaults itself from its own read-only font "new" object instance and works
      base.Font = Font;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Font property is an ambient property.  If it was never assigned, it automatically matches the Font property of the container control.  You never assigned it.

Do it like this:

```
public class MyTextbox : TextBox {
    Font mFont;
    public MyTextbox() {
        base.Font = mFont = new Font("Courier New", 12f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public override Font Font {
        get { return mFont; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work.  I pasted your code verbatim in and dragged that into my form.  Even before the control was allowed to be added it came back with

Failed to create componeent "myTextbox" ...System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Also, the code for my Command button was verbatim on the "Font" issue, and IT works perfectly... no extra property setting, and just immediately returns the font object via the GETter...